# Node red custom node that incorperates existing node red nodes

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes, node-red

I was wondering if there is any way to add an existing node red node into a custom node. An example would be something like the tcp in node or the debug node. These nodes could be "wired" internally inside of the custom node. For context I am working on a node to connect cameras to a robot for position and ai reading. The robot already has a costom add in developed. I know that it is best to have a custom node that has a very specific function and one function only but for the sake of simplicity for a user it would be best to incorperate a few nodes into this custom node.

I have tried using new RED.nodes.createNode(debugNode) and similar extensions of that class. Documentation for these classes is extremely hard to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some unorthodox methods of trying to do this the way that ended up working was to convert the flow to raw json and build a JavaScript function that could interpret that json. Hope this helps anyone doing something similar.

Comment: So you've re-implemented the Node-RED runtime, this doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no node inheritance or ways to "embed" an existing node in another node without directly copying the code.